# Linear independence of a set of mappings

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

$Map(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R}):=$ The set of all mappings from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

For every $a \in \mathbb{R}$ there is a Funktion $f_{a}:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with:

$$
f_{a}(x) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    (a-x)^{3} & \quad \text{if $x \le a$}\\
    0 & \quad \text{else}
  \end{array} \right.
$$

Show, that the Set $\{f_{a}|a \in \mathbb{R}\} $ in the real vector space $Map(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ is linear independent.

I wonder how to determine that there is no linear combination that equals zero, other than with all koefficients being zero. Any hints how to start on this?

Comment: Hint: you have to consider only finite linear combinations of the $f_a.$ If such a linear combination vanishes ientically, try to prove that the coefficient of the $f_a$ with the maximal value of $a$ must be $0.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\lambda_1f_{a_1}+\ldots+\lambda_nf_{a_n}=0$, where $a_1 < a_2 < \dots < a_n$. You need to show that $\lambda_1=0,...,\lambda_n=0$.

Now take $a_{n-1}<x_n<a_n$, then $\lambda_1f_{a_1}(x_n)+\ldots+\lambda_{n-1}f_{a_{n-1}}(x_n)+\lambda_{n}f_{a_{n}}(x_n)=0$ implies that $\lambda_{n}(a_n-x_n)^3=0$ thus $\lambda_{n}=0$; now proceed by induction.

Answer (score 1):

You have to show that if you have a finite linear combination of functions of the form $f_a$, which is identically zero, then all coefficients have to be zero. So let $\lambda_1f_{a_1}+\ldots+\lambda_nf_{a_n}=0$, that is, $\lambda_1f_{a_1}(x)+\ldots+\lambda_nf_{a_n}(x)=0$ for each $x\in\mathbb R$. We want to show that $\lambda_1=\ldots=\lambda_n=0$. Now, use that for each $x\leq a$ the function $f_a$ is a polynomial of degree 3. Then your linear combination is a polynomial also of degree 3 for $x\leq\min\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$, which is zero. What do you know about such polynomials?